# pandas iterate over rows and concat results automatically?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want to iterate over rows and to concat all the resulting dataframes preserving the original row information. I have a working example:

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list(range(3)), 'b': list(range(3))})

pd.concat(df.apply(lambda row: (
    pd.DataFrame(pd.np.zeros((row.a + row.b + 1, 2)), columns=['c', 'd']).assign(**row)
), axis=1).values).reset_index(drop=True)
     c    d  a  b
0  0.0  0.0  0  0
1  0.0  0.0  1  1
2  0.0  0.0  1  1
3  0.0  0.0  1  1
4  0.0  0.0  2  2
5  0.0  0.0  2  2
6  0.0  0.0  2  2
7  0.0  0.0  2  2
8  0.0  0.0  2  2
```

but I feel this is hacky. I would have guessed there is a *direct* way to concat all the results got from an `apply` (like in R). The things I dislike:

- adding initial values with `**row`
- using the underlying numpy array to use `pd.concat`
- `reset_index` because the final index is got from the new dataframe created in the loop instead of the original one.

Comment: This should be a dup. I have seen it somewhere on SO.

Comment: I tried to find it as well but could not. Sorry if it is

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to do? Why do you want to iterate over rows? Can't you think of a better way? Maybe if you tell us your actual problem we can give you better ideas.

Comment: yes I am missing the fact that I do iterate over rows because in my usecase I compute some values depending on values on row. I have edited the example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the duplicate. But IIUC, you are trying to do sort of `crosstab` on the two dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list(range(3)), 'b': list(range(3))})
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=('c','d'))

pd.concat((df2.loc[np.tile(df2.index, len(df))].reset_index(drop=True),
           df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(df2))].reset_index(drop=True)),
          axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   0   0
1   3   4   0   0
2   1   2   1   1
3   3   4   1   1
4   1   2   2   2
5   3   4   2   2
```

Or similarly:

```
common_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.index, df2.index))

out1 = df.reindex(common_idx.get_level_values(0)).set_index(common_idx)

out2 = df2.reindex(common_idx.get_level_values(1)).set_index(common_idx)

pd.concat((out2,out1),axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

outputs:

```
   c  d  a  b
0  1  2  0  0
1  3  4  0  0
2  1  2  1  1
3  3  4  1  1
4  1  2  2  2
5  3  4  2  2
```